# reactjs: socket.io try to connect to itself url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, socket.io

my reactjs run on http://111.333.11.22:3400
and i use nginx for proxy my https domain:

```
server {
  server_name pwa.mydomain.com www.pwa.mydomain.com;

  location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3400;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pwa.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pwa.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and this my reactjs code for connect to socket:

```
socket = io('https://other.com');
```

this socket connected to `https://other.com` successful.
but in my console i get this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://pwa.mydomain.com:3400/ws' failed
```

why `io` try to connect to itself url?!

note:
if i open directly http://111.333.11.22:3400, io connect to `https://other.com` successful and i dont get any console error